# If my website is hosted on IIS, how does Karma interact with it from Node JS?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, iis, iis-7.5, karma-runner

I'm getting started with Karma. My website is hosted on IIS on port 8081. Karma is configured to run on port 9876, on Node JS I presume. Will this work with them on different ports? If so, how do they interact?

Karma reports:

> Karma v0.12.21 - connected Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 7) is idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it doesn't.

Karma is leveraging node to provide the javascript execution environment to run your tests and also to provide a consistent app container of sorts to watch the filesystem for changes. It is not hitting your web server directly, unless you happen to be making an API call or something from your tests.